# Using the same word for twice in a single sentence

Tags: phrases, commas, conjunctions

1. **Each sensor** from the skeleton has different orientation values and **each sensor** is rotated individually to match the world coordinate system.
2. **Each sensor** from the skeleton has different orientation values and rotated individually to match the world coordinate system.

In the first sentence, “each sensor” is repeated. How can I modify it into a proper sentence?

In my second sentence, I used only “and”. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Each sensor from the skeleton **has** different orientation values and **is** rotated individually to match the world coordinate system.

You need both verbs, "has" and "is"  This is because you must explicitly keep what is *different* in the two sentences while removing what is the same.

You could however use "rotate" as an active verb

Each sensor from the skeleton **has** different orientation values and **rotates** individually to match the world coordinate system.

Comment: Can I omit the verb "is"? (Here, I am trying to write the second clause of the sentence in passive voice since the verb rotate can be used as an intransitive verb).

Comment: @Bharath Reddy  - I've added a paragraph to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is missing a comma before the “and” because it joins two independent clauses:

1. Each sensor has ..., and each sensor is ....

Otherwise, it is valid.

However, we avoid repeating a subject when we don’t need to:

2. Each sensor has ... and is ....

Note that there is no comma in this version since there is only one independent clause (with a compound predicate).

Since the verbs are different (“has” vs “is”), you need to keep both.